# What does it mean for a graph to be $P_3$-free (or more generally $P_k$-free)?

Tags: graph-theory

I'm confused on this. Does it mean that there is no induced subgraph that is $P_3$? Does it mean that any set of 3 connected vertices must be a triangle? Or, for $P_4$, a square?

Pictures would be super helpful if possible!

Comment: From the search "[P3 free graphs](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/21906/upperbound-the-order-of-p3-free-partition-of-p4-free-graphs)".

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "induced subgraph" necessary to define an $H$-free graph?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3084108/is-induced-subgraph-necessary-to-define-an-h-free-graph)